# Reference / replicate data error after delete row and append row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have the below code to copy last row from sheet 'form response', deleting row 2 from sheet 'InvData' and then appending the copy back in to sheet 'InvData' eg replacing with new data. This works ok

However after running this code the sheet 'Invoice' that references 'InvData' (eg =InvData!B2) for certain fields results in #REF! (reference does not exist) . Not sure why that is as the data is simply replaced in 'InvData'

```
function copyLastRow() {  
var target = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('InvData');
var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("form 
response");
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
var sourceData = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 53).getValues();
target.deleteRow(2); 
target.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function copyLastRow() {
  var target=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('InvData');
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("form response");
  var lastrow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceData=sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 53).getValues();
  target.getRange(2,1,1,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```